# SEO-специалист утверждает, что не стоит ставить в тексте 2 заголовка h2 подряд

Tags: seo, поисковая-оптимизация, продвижение

В итоге у заказчика в текстах на сайте везде заголовки идут: h1 h2 h3 h4. (Ну как будто бы цифра, это порядковый номер заголовка). Для меня как программиста это дикость. Что скажут другие SEO специалисты?

Уточню так, для лучшего понимания: Они считают, что лучше, чтобы на странице был ТОЛЬКО ОДИН h2, ТОЛЬКО ОДИН h3, ТОЛЬКО ОДИН H4 и т.д.

Поискал, не нашел каких-то примеров / четко прописанного в официальных инструкциях яндекса или и гугла правил, подтверждающих очевидное правило: Заголовок h1 - только один на странице, Заголовков h2-h5... - любое количество. Если кто поделиться ссылкой в официальном руководсве, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Уточню так, для лучшего понимания. Они считают, что лучше, чтобы на странице был ТОЛЬКО ОДИН h2, ТОЛЬКО ОДИН h3, ТОЛЬКО ОДИН H4.

Comment: Лучше править вопрос, чем уточнять его в комментариях

Answer (score 2):

Заголовки нужно использовать для того, для чего они нужны. Заголовки нужны не для нумерации абзацев. Как говорит Яндекс, "Правильное оформление заголовков в тексте помогает пользователю быстрее сориентироваться на странице". Если заголовки на странице отражают суть структуры документа - все в порядке, делайте хоть 10 `h2`. Страница сделана для людей — для робота плюс.

Естественно, что структура документа не обязана ограничиваться 6-ю заголовками, да еще и разными по весу. Ваш СЕО-специалист ошибается. Нормальная практика: один заголовок `h1`, остальных столько угодно. Лишь бы не было неправильной вложенности, вроде заголовков `h2` внутри `h3`.

Многие наши страницы в топе с кучей заголовков, по сравнительно высококонкурентным запросам.

Comment: Всё верно, я примерно также аргументировал. Но для убеждения не достает каких-то неопровержимых указаний из официальных статей яндекса или гугла на эту тему, не получается пока такого найти.

Comment: @ИльяАльтпромов Бремя доказательства лежит на утверждающем. Можно заявить что угодно - странно ожидать, что в интернете будет готовое опровержение любому утверждению любого сеошника. Вот он заявит, что процентное отношение точек и запятых на странице влияет на рейтинг - как вы будете опровергать?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что Google вам конкретно не скажет сколько нужно использовать заголовков H1, H2 или H3, один или два. Уходят от конкретики. Все зависит от ситуации.

Есть видеообращения, где об этом рассказывают эксперты.

*On February 26, 2009, Google software engineer Matt Cutts*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM

Matt Cutts отметил:

- Если есть логическая причина использовать H1 на странице - Ок.
- Не стоить оформлять весь текст как H1, и править его используя CSS.
- Если злоупотреблять, используя повсюду H1, то алгоритмы поисковой
  системы примут это во внимание.
- Используйте его там, где есть в этом смысл и экономнее, но вы можете
  использовать его несколько раз.

*«So I would use it where it make sense and more sparingly, but you can have it multiple times.»*

Еще одна статья, где говорят, что можно использовать несколько раз, но на своем примере говорят, что используют H1 один раз. И общая инфо. о заголовках H2-H6.

https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/

Еще одно мнение

https://moz.com/community/q/is-single-h1-tag-still-best-practice

*«главная задача должна заключаться в создании исключительного контента, не имеющего более одного тега H1»*

Рекомендую посмотреть на конкурентов, на сайты которые в ТОП по вашей тематике. Как и сколько раз они используют заголовок  H1, H2, H3.